# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.int32

Tags: python

I got the following error when i=0 in the below loop. I don't know why? If I test the code in a separate program and it is fine. why? Thanks for your help

Code that doesn't work:

```
for i in np.arange(0,delta.days+1,0.5):   
    print('day=',i)
    print(tick_min)
    nextdate = tick_min + timedelta(days=i)
```

Output:

```
day= 0
2021-01-30 17:20:38
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.int32
```

As a separate program, it is working:

```
import datetime

tick_min=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 30, 17, 20, 38)

nextdate = tick_min + timedelta(days=0)
print(nextdate)
```

Output:

```
2021-01-30 17:20:38
```

Comment: Convert that value to a plain integer.  `timedelta(days=int(i))`

Comment: Yes it worked.Thanks John, can you tell why? why numpy.int32 is not working?

Comment: Hi John, how do I accept this answer?

Comment: @roudan. That's not an answer. It's a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @John Gordon pointed out casting to an integer should solve this `TypeError`.
However, newer versions of the `DateTime` library support both `int` and `float` values for the days component of the `timedelta` method.
Here is the relevant passage from DateTime's documentation [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#:%7E:text=Arguments%20may%20be%20integers%20or%20floats).

Judging by the first code snippet, the one that contains the loop over the `np.arange` vector, it seems that you expect the `days` argument in `timedelta` to be a primitive of type `float`. Thus, casting `days` to an integer may lead to wrong results.

The actual issue here seems to be that the numpy vector defaults to a `dtype="np.int32"`, due to the arguments that you pass and most probably to the version of numpy that you have installed on your system. You could address this issue by either casting to a `float` or substituting `np.arange(0, delta.days + 1, 0.5)` for `np.arange(0, delta.days + 1, 0.5, dtype='float')` in your loop, as using any other type either than `np.int64`,`np.int`,`np.float64`, `np.float` will trigger a `TypeError`.

**EDIT**

@Reti43 suggested the following [bug tracker issue resource](https://bugs.python.org/issue5476) identifying the reason other `numpy.dtype` (`np.int8`, `np.int16`, `np.int32`, `np.float16`, `np.float32` etc) objects lead to a `TypeError` as the lack of inheritance of these objects from the primitive type objects `int` and `float`, respectively.

Comment: Thank kalgoritmi, that is awesome! Were you saying using np.arange(0,4,0.5) will return np.int32 even I am using arange with step of 0.5? The reason I was using arange instead of range() was thinking np.arange will return float? Am I correct?

Comment: This indeed seems odd, but that was the conclusion drawn upon the raised `TypeError`. For some reason it deduced the type as `np.int32`

Comment: @roudan In any case explicitly specifying the `dtype` when using numpy functions can save you from headaches later on